# How to add liquid pump and extrenal power supply part to fritzing?

Tags: esp32

I have a question regarding the power supply and the liquid pump. I have a project about automatic pump with ESP32. So, I want to try my solution in fritzing before order the devices. unfortunately, I can't find the power supply and the liquid pump file to add them for fritzing?

Comment: Have you tried [Fritzing Parts Lab](https://fritzing.org/parts/) and [Github](https://github.com/fritzing/fritzing-parts)? Perhaps the ["Creating Custom Parts" tutorial](https://fritzing.org/learning/tutorials/creating-custom-parts/) might help.

Comment: A better way to put the question would be presenting the scenario, with a solution you could think of, then finding more ways to tackle. This way people who are answering you can have more clarity and better solutions.

Comment: @AgiHammerthief  Yes i search in fritzing parts Lab and Github but i can't find those parts